# Firebase iOS Facebook authentication doesn't work if Facebook app is installed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have Firebase Authentication for Facebook implemented.

If I log into facebook from my safari browser, and then use Facebook login on my firebase iOS app. It authenticates correctly. So the fundamental integration works.

However if I logoff from the browser or never log in to begin with, and try to login using facebook auth from my app. If you have the facebook app installed and logged in, it will attempt to log in using the app. Here it fails to authorize and simply returns you to the login page.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there something special required to allow handing off to facebook auth through facebook app successfully?

Here's what gets logged when the authentication fails.

2020-09-28 21:02:25.486277-0400 Flixxaid[3832:875073] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C17] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-09-28 21:02:25.504312-0400 Flixxaid[3832:875073] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C18] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-09-28 21:02:25.571637-0400 Flixxaid[3832:875509] 6.32.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023000] Deep Link Web URL query is empty
User cancelled login
2020-09-28 21:02:26.001549-0400 Flixxaid[3832:875074] [tcp] tcp_input [C23.1:3] flags=[R] seq=3148860654, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3148860654, snd_una=3733900017
2020-09-28 21:02:26.002891-0400 Flixxaid[3832:875074] [tcp] tcp_input [C23.1:3] flags=[R] seq=3148860654, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3148860654, snd_una=3733900017

Comment: Do you have `ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` and `Profile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and also do you have `open url` implemented properly?

Comment: I did NOT have Profile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true). 
Add it. But behaviour is still the same. Facebook app opens asking to Continue .. but then it just returns to my login page. 

2020-09-29 21:01:48.835865-0400 Flixxaid[1083:283040] 6.32.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023000] Deep Link Web URL query is empty
User cancelled login

Yet if I sign in to facebook from the safari browser. Facebook app is bypassed, so FB auth from my app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my coding error... Here was my original code from `AppDelegate.swift`:

```swift
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  guard let link = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) else { return false }
  self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(link)
  let handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
  let fbHandler = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url,
    sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
    annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
  )
  // DynamicLinks.performDiagnostics(completion: nil)
  return handled || fbHandler
}
```

And here is the correct version that supports condition to handle FB, Google and Dynamic Links correctly...

```swift
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  var dlHandler = false
  if let link = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
    self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(link)
    dlHandler = true
  }
  let handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
  let fbHandler = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url,
    sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
    annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
  )
  // DynamicLinks.performDiagnostics(completion: nil)
  return handled || fbHandler || dlHandler
}
```